# Model fails in validation but is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

I'm facing an issue for a long time now. The code I have is the following:

```
class BrokenModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with BrokenValidator

  has_many :association_name
end

class BrokenValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate record
    @record = record

    check_alerted
  end

  private

  def check_alerted
    return if @record.association_name.to_a.empty?

    alerted = <test for alerted>
    if alerted
      @record.errors[:base] << "It was alerted recently"
    end

    p "check_alerted: #{@record.errors[:base]}"
  end
end
```

worker.rb

```
[...]
BrokenModel.create(association_name: [model1, model2])
[...]
```

In my logs for the last print is shows that the validation passed only once, but I have actually multiple entries created for this model with `association_name` present.

My environment is running this in multiple threads and multiple cores, but as the entries are created minutes away from each other, it is not a concurrency issue, unless an exception in a separated thread is affecting the model creation.

Just for curiosity sake, this is running in a Sidekiq worker.

**Edit**

So I noticed in my logs, that it might be a concurrency issue. So here is what is happening:

- instance 1 validation: alerted recently: failed (It was alerted recently)
- instance 2 validation: alerted recently: passed
- instance 2 validation: other validation: failed (Other validation)
- instance 2 creation errors: It was alerted recently + Other validation
- instance 1 creation errors: None

Any clue if there is any kind of thread unsafety in ActiveModel::Validator or the @record might be overwritten/shared by other threads?

Comment: whats mean `<test for alerted>`, can u explain it, pls ?

Comment: It is a method that checks in redis for the presence of and ID. 

It is not that useful, because if the method was returning wrong values, it would be either throwing an exception or would reach check_alerted log empty.

Comment: Is there a chance of association_name be empty in the validation stage, and filled later in the persistence cycle even though it is injected in the create command?

Answer (score 2):

Adding errors to a record does NOT make it invalid.  In fact when the model is validated before save,  all previous errors including the one you're adding in your code are erased.

Do this validation in the model... Not in the worker.

```
validate :check_alerted

def check_alerted
   return if association_name.to_a.empty?
    alerted = test 
    if <test for alerted> 
      errors.add(:base, "It was alerted recently") 
   end 
end
```

Comment: Sorry, the code is not complete. The creation is running in Sidekiq, but the validation is in the model. Just fixing the question.

Comment: It's in the model but you're referring to an instance variable `@record`?

Comment: It was not the correct answer, though it was useful and I though the problem was with my logs search.